# Finding Paths between Parent Node and specific Child Nodes in a Tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

Apologies in advance for the open-ended nature of this question but I'm currently brainstorming a way to tackle an automation problem using Python. A set of data I'm analyzing can be thought of as a tree that looks like the following:

[image: Example of Tree Structure]

There are two parts to my question, first the tricky portion, and then more of a general implementation question.

1. For a given top level parent node (a node which has no parent), how do I find the path to a bottom level child node (a node with no children) ONLY for bottom nodes that are in a set of values I define? For instance if I define the set of values as "B" and "F" only, I would only want to extract the path from A to B and A to F only. As in, I should get [A -> Y -> B] and [A -> Z -> C -> F] as an answer.
2. Given the requirements above, what is the best way to represent these trees in Python? My original thought was nested dictionaries where each node is defined as a dictionary key. Keep in mind the example I gave is a simple one. I will be building these trees for many different top level parents, and each top level parent may have many, many child nodes.

Comment: Is the subset of requested nodes going to be very small compared to the set of total leaves? If not (or if performance isn't an issue because the trees are always tiny), you can just iterate all leaves (using a simple depth-first or breadth-first search) and filter it on "is this leaf in the set of desired leaves?"

Comment: @abarnert that makes sense, the subset is going to actually be a pretty big portion of the total leaves and I'm not very worried about performance. This is sort of a "one and done" type script so as long as it runs relatively quickly iterating through all leaves should work well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of desired leaves is on the same order as the number of leaves, the simplest solution is just to build a generic iterator over *all* paths, and then just filter it on matches. For example:

```
def find_paths(self, targets):
    targets = set(targets)
    for path in self.iter_all_paths_dfs():
        if path[-1].name in targets:
            yield path
```

(Or course you can condense that down to a single generator expression or `filter` call, but I wrote it out explicitly to make it obvious.)

---

And if you can do it this way, you don't need back-pointers or next-pointers, so a node can be a dict mapping child names to child nodes, as you suggested.

However, it's often simpler to think of a node as a name, plus a collection of children. Compare:

```
class Node(collections.namedtuple('Node', ('name', 'children'))):
    def iter_node_names_dfs(self):
        yield self.name
        for child in self.children:
            yield from child.iter_node_names_dfs()

E = Node('E', ())
F = Node('F', ())
C = Node('C', (E, F))
D = Node('D', ())
Z = Node('Z', (C, D))
X = Node('X', ())
A = Node('A', (X, Z))
tree = A
```

to:

```
E = {}
F = {}
C = {'E': {}, 'F': {}}
D = {}
Z = {'C': C, 'D': D}
X = {}
A = {'X': X, 'Z': Z}
tree = {'A': A}

def iter_node_names_dfs(tree):
    for name, child in tree.items():
        yield name
        yield from iter_node_names_dfs(child)
```

Notice that the dict solution requires an extra node to point at A so you can hold its name, and it also means that you can't get a node's name from the node; you have to remember it from the previous step.

As far as space goes, there's not much difference, but of course you can test (by recursing and summing up `sys.getsizeof(node)` if that's a concern).

Comment: Awesome! Very clear explanation and the implementation makes a lot of sense. This gives a great starting point for this project, appreciate the help!